# SELECT Statement but I'm not sure how to isolate year or the month from Date

Tags: mysql, sql

The question asks for a query that satisfies this: "List the EventCode and Year for all shows that are scheduled in the month of December. Your query should display each event code only once."

It has to be structured as a select statement, but I'm not entirely sure on how to isolate the year or the month from ShowDate.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the mysql function "month(date).

You can select the month from your database by querying:

```
select month(showDate) from eventshow;
```

Further details can be found here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: Please have a look on the answer from @Elzo Valugi

Answer (score 1):

MONTH(ShowDate) and YEAR(ShowDate) are predefined mysql functions that work over Date columns. DISTINCT is used to get the elements only one. It will be a good idea to have an index on ShowDate column.

Your query will be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EventCode 
FROM eventshow 
WHERE
    MONTH(ShowDate) = 12 AND YEAR(ShowDate) = 2015;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the query you have to write correctly (and I am assuming it is MySQL), it should look like this:

```
SELECT e.EventCode, MAX(YEAR(e.ShowDate)) AS Year FROM eventshow e
  WHERE MONTH(e.ShowDate) = 12
  GROUP BY e.EventCode;
```

Question is: how to handle year? (because you didn't specify what year to print if there are mutliple with single eventcode)

You can use any aggregate function, depending on what you need.

[image]

Rest of the code I used for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE eventshow
(
    `EventCode` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `ShowDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00', 
    `ShowTime` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00', 
    `TicketPrice` int(5) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`EventCode`,`ShowDate`,`ShowTime`)
    -- CONSTRAINT `eventshow_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EventCode`) REFERENCES `event` (`EventCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

INSERT INTO eventshow (eventshow.EventCode, eventshow.ShowDate, eventshow.ShowTime, eventshow.TicketPrice)
  VALUES (1, '2012-11-12', '01:11:10', 30);
INSERT INTO eventshow (eventshow.EventCode, eventshow.ShowDate, eventshow.ShowTime, eventshow.TicketPrice)
  VALUES (1, '2012-12-11', '00:11:10', 40);
INSERT INTO eventshow (eventshow.EventCode, eventshow.ShowDate, eventshow.ShowTime, eventshow.TicketPrice)
  VALUES (2, '2012-10-08', '02:33:30', 50);
INSERT INTO eventshow (eventshow.EventCode, eventshow.ShowDate, eventshow.ShowTime, eventshow.TicketPrice)
  VALUES (2, '2012-12-08', '03:53:30', 60);
INSERT INTO eventshow (eventshow.EventCode, eventshow.ShowDate, eventshow.ShowTime, eventshow.TicketPrice)
  VALUES (2, '2013-12-03', '04:23:20', 70);
INSERT INTO eventshow (eventshow.EventCode, eventshow.ShowDate, eventshow.ShowTime, eventshow.TicketPrice)
  VALUES (2, '2013-12-07', '05:23:10', 80);
```